# How to get the view from a region in PRISM?

Tags: c#, module, prism, ioc-container, region

I'm using PRISM and I'm trying to get the view, but returns null the function `GetView()`.

What am I doing wrong?

```
    public void Initialize()
    {
        _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("TopLeftRegion", () => _container.Resolve<View1>());
        _container.RegisterType<Object, View1>("ViewB");

        var view = _regionManager.Regions["TopLeftRegion"].GetView("ViewB");
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason it is returning null is because there are no views with the name "ViewB".  When you use RegisterViewWithRegion, Prism activates a new instance of the view type (in your case View1>.  However, there is no way to name that instance for the views collection using that technique.

To accomplish what you want to do, you need to add a view **that you instantiate yourself** to the region.

```
_regionManager.Regions["TopLeftRegion"].Add(new View1(),"ViewB");

var view = _regionManager.Regions["TopLeftRegion"].GetView("ViewB");
```

More information can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism.regions.iregion_members%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx)